# Pull Printer data into one centeral location

Tags: html, printing

I'm trying to create a central location to display printer names, type, toner status, drum, IP...How many times the toner has been replaced (possible query for dates?). 
I would like the toner status to turn the line red when under 25%.

The main issue I'm having is how. I'm fairly new at the IT game and I've had a few programming courses but nothing that makes me too confident. What is the best way to do this?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to pull printer data and display it. Where is the printer ? on the machine ? network printer ?? What OS are you using ? you want to use html for that ?

Comment: The printers that I want to monitor are all in the same building, just different offices. Our print server is Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise. Some of them are network printers (CEO printers are off the grid). I want to find the most efficient way to get the data but I am at a road block. I can't figure out how to get that data out and onto one place.

Comment: It's a vast subject... I don't know where to start even. Are all the printers connected to the same server ? or is it like each printer connected to the computer in the specific office ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific when I asked. They are all on the same print server. I picked up a C# book and I think I'm going to try and download the API's from the manufacture's site. I'm just so new to it all and I know one book isn't going to make me an instant programmer.

Comment: Cool... Then good luck.. get back if you encounter any problems in your code...